# Can you recognize this virus?

Tags: virus, windows-10, virus-removal

Yesterday i noticed a folder with a strange name, it looked like this from the inside:
[image]

I was cautions not open any of the files, but i opened the .sql in a text-editor, to realize it's not SQL but some hash, i renamed the folder to "virus" to remind myself to google the content later, but then i noticed another folder that didn't exist, it must have been created after i renamed the folder, and this time it has a different names:
[image]

Then it jumped/copied it self to all partitions on the hard desk.
Each folder is exactly 1.83 MB with the same file structure.
My computer is behaving normally but i might re-install the OS if i couldn't find a way to remove this virus.

so...
Can you recognize this virus? What category it might belong to?

Comment: You can upload and test the files on virustotal.com
Maybe you'll get some idea

Comment: @PriyankGupta Oh that's a good idea, but it actually gave me all green

Comment: None of those file names come up in google so i presume they are randomised (including extensions).  If VT hasn't found anything and your local anti virus hasn't either there are plenty more online tools - housecall, bitdefender, eset, f secure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you installed [Cybereason RansomFree](https://ransomfree.cybereason.com/).

This writes two folders with 'random' file names to each of your partitions, and one to the desktop labeled *This folder protects against ransomware. Modifying it will reduce protection*<sup>*</sup> (which you will only see if you have configured Windows to show hidden/system files).

The program monitors these folders for ransomware activity, and regularly rewrites them. The file contents are gibberish, you can't open one of these .xls files in Excel, etc.

So, not a virus.
Here is a sample folder from my drive:

[image]

<sup>* Actual text changes with version. They have been updating the program several times over the past few weeks.</sup>

Comment: That is actually true, i have Cybereason RansomFree...