# Found some mysterious folders in each of my drive in windows 10

Tags: windows, malware, virus, windows-10

Today while investigating the frequent freeze of my windows 10 machine I found some mysterious folders in each of my drive containing some files. Folders are hidden and readonly. Most of these files do not open but some files open but have text not understandable.

like in

> **C Drive contains**
>
> *Folder name :* `Xstorage172`
>
> **Contains Files**
>
> `arrange-meaning.rtf - 89KB
>   gave-thick-found-shopping.pem - 50KB
>   independenceplasterbombers.docx - 272KB
>   jointhumblelendreplacement.mdb - 198KB
>   laboratory complement amongst manufacturer.sql - 19KB
>   mike-changes.txt - 39KB
>   one_pursue_degree_succeeded.jpg - 276KB
>   screw.chamber.quantity.divide.xlsx - 495KB
>   touch_guess_goal.doc UOA1ao6zzjvk.xls - 400KB
>   UOA1ao6zzjvk.xls - 69KB`

---

> **D Drive contains two folders**
>
> `Vcaches191` and `ysystem45`
>
> **Vcaches191 folder contains Files**
>
> `accordingly_person_nato_spectrum.xlsx
>   clubs.production.confirmed.therefore.doc 
>   CSW.docx detriment education deck focus.rtf 
>   devil_numerous_higher.jpg 
>   innovationyork.txt 
>   interviews consequent sword bearing.xls 
>   receive_relatively.mdb
>   resistance.dominated.processes.pem 
>   rope visual voting.sql`

and

**ysystem45 folder contains files**

> `8EAo.xlsx 
>   coefficient.language.race.pem 
>   completelywindsadult.mdb
>   dense annoy species.docx 
>   graduatecumbersome.xls 
>   lift formerlyorder.txt 
>   LKZlHp2Fyq1.rtf 
>   swept-males-snakes.jpg 
>   whereas furnish want.doc 
>   xbP3GhRM.sql`

*See the pattern. Each folder have same type of files but with different names.*
Is this some kind of virus or malware???

One more thing. Files' create date is of today's when I turned on the system.

---

**Files' content links** (due to less than 10 reps I am unable to link all files in seperate links. I am pasting link of my "pastebin" profile where you can find contents of following files.)

`C:\Xstorage172\gave-thick-found-shopping.pem
C:\Xstorage172\laboratory complement amongst manufacturer.sql
C:\Xstorage172\mike-changes.txt`

[Pastebin profile](http://pastebin.com/u/Mutahhar)

Comment: *Hello, and welcome to InfoSec Exchange*, part of the Stack Exchange family of sites. It certainly looks like several files with random English words put together with some arbitrary extension placed on the end. Could you possibly give some file sizes, and the contents of the files?

Comment: @dark_st3alth
Most of the files give error while opening. like `.xlsx`, `.docx`, `.jpg` etc. only `.pem`, `.sql`, `.txt` can be opened but have very long text that can not b put in question due to character limitation. Let me put content of those file some where else and link them here.

Comment: Interestingly enough, they look like PGP blocks in the files. I haven't seen something like this before...

Comment: Looks similar to this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148511/can-you-recognize-this-virus/148514#148514

Comment: @iain
Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I have actually installed Cybereason RansomFree

Comment: This question is better worded than the other one it leads to. Useful question title, filenames in text not in pictures...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names are generated, so you definitely it looks like some kind of infestation.

But it looks like RansomFree, a program that creates fake known types of files and monitors these files, and whenever they change, it detects the originating process and pauses it.

Be aware that other malware may trick you and do something similar.

Comment: Something that does that to your HDD I consider an infection. I will update the answer.